# Measuring Requests per second using statsd

Tags: statsd

I want to measure Requests per second using Statsd?

Currently, I am using increment counter, So whenever a new request comes it will increment by 1?

In this case, I was able to capture cumulative data rather than request count per second.

So what I need was flush counter data every second and delete that counter, so that we will get data for that second only.

Is it possible to do so in Statsd?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [metric types docs](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/metric_types.md), Statsd will send both the rate as well as the count at each flush. Also, according to [the code comments](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/ff845ebed8b2bae299aba98c536d45e78212f0fb/backends/graphite.js#L181), this rate is per second, so it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I am using statsd plugin of collectd, I didn't find any rate in collectd. I there is in collectd also, can you help me with that

Comment: From statsd you have the count every ten seconds, just divide. :D